# Accidentally wiped /system, recovery not working

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb, factory-reset, fastboot

I accidentally wiped /system on my Archos 101e Neon (MT8163) through fastboot. Now it can't boot and can't go to recovery or fastboot mode. I tried vol -, vol + and both. It's just stuck on the first boot splash with the "Orange State: Your device has been unlocked" message. It also seems to not be detected by the PC (I'm running Linux). Any way to recover this brick?

Comment: my phone usually stays for 120 seconds on that 5 seconds screen, so i have to keep holding volume up for 120 seconds